# div not expanding to full height of background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and want a full width div to go 100% height on a background image. I can't figure out why its collapsing to just the line height. Any ideas? See fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/aartese/3kRVm/

```
 <body>   
  <row><!--landing section -->
     <div class="col-md-12 landing">Landing</div>
  </row> <!-- /landing section -->
  <row><!--about section -->
    <div class="col-md-12 about">About</div>
  </row><!-- /about section -->
  <row><!-- professional profile section -->
    <div class="col-md-12 professional">Professional</div>
  </row><!-- /professional profile section -->
  <row> <!-- contact section -->
    <div class="col-md-12 contact">Contact</div>
  </row> <!-- /contact section -->    
 </body>
```

Comment: A background image cannot affect the dimension of the element to which it is the background. Also,. there is no such HTML element as `row`.

Comment: Which `div` do you want to stretch to 100%? You'd have to set `height: 100%;` on `html` & `body` to have a `div` take up the page: http://jsfiddle.net/3kRVm/1/

Comment: whoops, it should be <div class="row">

Answer (score 0):

Is [that](http://jsfiddle.net/3kRVm/2/) what you meant? The basic concept is copied from Ryan Fait's [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/). It basically revolves around ensuring that all the parent elements' `min-height` and `height` are 100%